# Image embedded in email also becomes an attachment

Tags: python, email, html-email, email-attachments, mime

A script that is correctly embedding inline images in HTML emails, is also adding the images as attachments. How can I eliminate this second copy of each image?

If any intended attachments are included, they're processing correctly. With or without attachments, all images appear in the body of the message, and then again as an attachment. Removing the section for attachments (# Attach any files) makes no difference on the images. They still get included twice.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
import mimetypes

strFrom = 'Me@some.com'
strPWord = 'XYZ'
strTo = 'Recipient@GMail.com'

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'This is a test at 1:22'
msg['From'] = strFrom 
msg['To'] = strTo 
msg.set_content('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
                    <p><img src="cid:image1"/></p>
                    <p>Python email test</p>
                    <p><img src="cid:image2"/></p>
    </body>
</html>
''', subtype='html')

msg.make_mixed()

# Attach Any Images
images = '''/Users/my/Desktop/RKw.jpeg\n/Users/my/Desktop/logo.png'''.splitlines()
i=1
for image in images:
    # print 'Image',i,': ',image,'\n'
    fp = open(image, 'rb')
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    # Define the image's ID as referenced above
    msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image'+str(i)+'>')
    msg.attach(msgImage)
    i+=1


# Attach any files
files = ''''''.splitlines()
for file in files:
    ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file)
    if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
        ctype = 'application/octet-stream'
    maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        msg.add_attachment(fp.read(),
                           maintype=maintype,
                           subtype=subtype,
                           filename=file.split('/')[-1].replace(' ','%20'))
                               
                                                 
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtpserver.com', 465) as smtp:
    smtp.login(strFrom, strPWord) 
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Are you sure there are two copies in the message? That's how inline images work, they're sent as an attachment that's referenced with a `cid:` URL in the main message.

Comment: The image(s) appear within the body of the HTML email just fine, using cid. The issue is that in the received email, they all appear a second time following the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to attach a single image and then use it in different places of the message body, you can attach it once and use `CID` attribute for referring to the embedded image without re-attaching the file anew. The same attached file will be used that way.

Comment: Where do you see them attaching the same image twice? Please show the change to the code you're recommending.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check the HTML markup of the received messages to find out why images are duplicated?

Comment: And to recommend any changes we must see the entire source code, not just a piece of code which can't explain why you got two images on the recipient side.